# devise ajax sign in handling failure on rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I am trying to receive login fail events on a devise AJAX login form. I have overriden the devise sessions controller like so:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => '#{controller_path}#failure')
    sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    resource ||= resource_or_scope
    sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
    return render :json => {:success => true}
  end

  def failure
    return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
  end
end
```

the json on failure never actually triggers on a 401 unauthorised response. The js on sign_in_and_redirect works fine though.

Here is the section of my js where i expect an alert to show:

```
$(document).on('click', '#login-btn', function(){
    $("#login-modal").toggleClass("is-active");
    $("form#login_user_form").bind("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
        if (data.success) {
            $("#login-modal").toggleClass("is-active");
        } else {
            return alert('failure!'); // this never happens
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT - So I managed to get the desired behaviour by checking for `data.status == 200` instead of `data.success` ... I am still wondering if this is the right way to go about it or if I'm missing something

Comment: What happens when you `return alert(xhr)` before your `if` block

Comment: Also try `.bind`ing `ajax:complete` and putting the result in there instead e.g. `.on('ajax:complete', function (e, xhr, status, error) {alert(xhr);});`

Comment: Any updated status about your issue?

Comment: @Jonathan so I tried checking for data.status == 200 and it works, see edit above. Wondering if this is the right way to go about it. I tried binding to the ajax:complete event like you mentioned, but it had the same issue. checking status worked though

Comment: That doesn't seem like a solution to me. Don't you need it to return whether or not login succeeded? The status is completely unrelated. You should dump out what kind of information you get back from `complete` with `xhr` et. al

Comment: @Jonathan it does trigger the appropriate behaviour. If login is not successful, the http status code is 401 and not 200 therefore the alert shows

Comment: Ah I see... yes... if it is responding with an appropriate HTTP response code then you can use it. I was under the impression that this may not necessarily be depended upon to give you the appropriate feedback. So you solved your own question in the end.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks, and thank you for taking the time to look at my question

Answer (score 4):

It could be that your ajax is not firing your `success` at all. So try handling the other ajax events and inspecting the result to help you debug if you haven't done so already:

```
$(document).on('click', '#login-btn', function() {
  $("#login-modal").toggleClass("is-active");
  $("form#login_user_form").bind("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    if (data.success) {
      $("#login-modal").toggleClass("is-active");
    } else {
      return alert('failure!');
    }
  }).bind("ajax:complete", function(e, xhr, status, error) { // <----
    return alert(xhr);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by checking the http status code like so:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#login-btn', function(){
    $("#login-modal").toggleClass("is-active");
    $("form#login_user_form").bind("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
        if (data.status == 200) { // check for http status code here
            $("#login-modal").toggleClass("is-active");
        } else {
            return alert('failure!'); // this now works on failed sign in 
        }
    });
});
```

if the sign in fails, `data.status` is 401 unauthorized and therefore logical flow goes to the else condition